# Java 6 / 7 Decompiling Command Line

Tags: java, decompiler

I'm aware that part of this has been asked before however my search continues empty handed. Currently I'm using JD-Gui to decompile jar files and have switched to fernflower but it seems to have issues with enumeration, will not decompile specific classes by throwing an NPE. I've even went to the extend of trying Jode, JAD, and even using JD-Core (extracted 0.6.1 Snapshot/modified/loaded native from the JD-IntellJ plugin) but are all riddled with errors, bytecode, ect. (Other than JD-Core 0.6.2 in JD-Gui) My question is has anyone found a reasonable decompiler that can handle Java 6 / 7 , that can be accessed via command line or even a library that has been yet to be discovered.

Comment: My prayer was answered. Procyon.

Comment: I had the exact same question and I am surprised by the lack if interest in this thread. @user2080413: As per your suggestion, I looked at [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) and it looks like the developer is actively working on this project and there are several versions available from over the last few months. Also, its FOSS which IMO is how such a project should be made. Most other java decompilers had some proprietary aspects and for one reason or another have not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well back in my days in reverse engineering, i used to have this one in my toolkit,

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/DJ-Java-Decompiler.shtml. It's trial-ware though, but i've found it useful, not to mention that you always have ida-pro as a good weapon of choice.